# How to remove a child element with simple dom html

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I would like to remove th 4 in this html with **Child selector** of [PHP Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) without id/class

```
<tr>
  <th>some text</th>
  <th>some text</th>
  <th>some text</th>
  <th>some text</th>
  <th>some text</th>
  <th>some text</th>
  <th>some text</th>
  <th>some text</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: You can use jquery for this

Comment: like only PHP Simple HTML DOM

Answer (score 1):

Taking `$tr` as the row you're using, you can select the child with the following:

```
$fourthTh = $tr->children(4)
```

You can then remove the child using [`DOMNode::removeChild()`](http://php.net/DOMNode.removeChild) on the parent element:

```
$tr->removeChild($fourthTh)
```